# Unable to style todo button in todo list html css JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am able to add and delete and check the items done and also able to add new item with click of add button. All complete and remove buttons are visible along with the add button. But, On clicking the add button, when I get to add the new item, I can only see the tiny size of the complete and remove buttons for the newly added items and when I try to style these 2 buttons It doesn't respond. Strangely,  same buttons are ok for existing items I keyed into my html code. Something is wrong with my css code but unable  to figure out.
Thanks if someone can point out.

```js
/**add click function to add the new item to input field**/

document.getElementById("new").addEventListener("click", function() {
  /**define item variable to be added. Item is actually the value of the input text with id "inputText" **/
  var task = document.getElementById("text").value;
  /** if got some item to add, add the new item to input field**/
  if (task != "") {
    addNewTask(task);


    /**clear input field **/
    document.getElementById("text").value = "";
  }
});

//function addNewTask(item){
/**add new todo to todo list**/
/**var list = document.getElementById("todos");
  var newItem = document.createElement("li");
  newItem.innerText = item;
  var buttons = document.createElement("div");
  buttons.classList.add("buttons");
  var completed = document.createElement("button");
  completed.classList.add("completed");
  completed.addEventListener('click', completedItem);
  
 var delete  =document.createElement("button");
  delete.classList.add("delete");
  delete.addEventListener("click", deleteItem);
  buttons.appendChild(completed);
 buttons.appendChild(delete);
 
  newItem.appendChild(buttons);
}

var deleteIt = document.getElementByClassName("delete");
 for(var i = 0; i < deleteIt.length; i++){
   deleteIt[i].addEventListener("click", deleteItem)
 }

var changeIt= document.getElementByClassName("completed");
 for(var i = 0; i < changeIt.length; i++){
   changeIt[i].addEventListener("click", completedItem)
 }
**/

function removeItem() {
  var item = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  var parent = item.parentNode;
  parent.removeChild(item);
}

function completeItem() {
  var item = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  var parent = item.parentNode;
  var parentId = parent.id;

  //to be able to change between completed and uncomplete items both ways
  var target = (parentId === "todo") ? document.getElementById("ready") : document.getElementById("todo");

  parent.removeChild(item);
  target.insertBefore(item, target.childNodes[0]);
}

//Adds new item to todo list
function addNewTask(item) {
  var list = document.getElementById("todo");

  var newItem = document.createElement("li");
  newItem.innerText = item;

  var buttons = document.createElement("div");
  buttons.classList.add("buttons");

  //creates remove and complete buttons + add classes
  var remove = document.createElement("button");
  remove.classList.add("remove");
  remove.addEventListener("click", removeItem);

  var complete = document.createElement("button");
  complete.classList.add("complete");
  complete.addEventListener("click", completeItem);

  buttons.appendChild(remove);
  buttons.appendChild(complete);
  newItem.appendChild(buttons);

  //insert new todo before the first element
  list.insertBefore(newItem, list.childNodes[0]);
}


//add event listener to pre-made list items

var deleteIt = document.getElementsByClassName("remove");
for (var i = 0; i < deleteIt.length; i++) {
  deleteIt[i].addEventListener("click", removeItem);
}

var changeIt = document.getElementsByClassName("complete");
for (var i = 0; i < changeIt.length; i++) {
  changeIt[i].addEventListener("click", completeItem);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#todoApp {
  width: 370px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

header {
  background: deepskyblue;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px 60px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom: 7px solid black;
}

input {
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
}

#new {
  background: black;
  color: red;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  padding: 2px;
  height: 40px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 370px;
  border-left: 2px solid grey;
  border-right: 2px solid grey;
  border-top: 7px solid black;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 90px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
  color: black;
  padding: 7px 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 9px;
}

.add {
  height: 45px;
  width; 60px;
  float: right;
  color: red;
  background: white;
}

#ready {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: red;
}

.buttons {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="todoApp">
  <header>
    <h1>Todo App</h1>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text" placeholder="Enter some task" />
    <div class="add">
      <button id="new"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="color: white;"></i></button></div>

  </header>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="todo">
      <li>Learn Html
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="complete" style="border:none; color:red;"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:red;"></i></button>

          <button class="remove" style="border:none"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="color:red;"></i> </button>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>Learn CSS
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="complete" style="border:none"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:red;"></i>
      
      
</button>
          <button class="remove" style="border:none"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="color:red;"></i></button>
        </div>
      </li>


    </ul>
    <ul id="ready">
      <li>Finish book
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="complete" style="border:none"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:red;"></i></button>
          <button class="remove" style="border:none"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="color:red;"></i></button>




        </div>
      </li>
      <li>Learn Python
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="complete" style="border:none"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:red;"></i></button>
          <button class="remove" style="border:none"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="color:red;"></i>
      </button>

        </div>


      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `width; 60px;` is probably not what you meant to type?

Comment: You're adding two empty buttons which just have a complete/remove class. No sign anywhere of a font awesome <i> tag or any attempt to style them in your CSS. https://jsfiddle.net/8ntrq2oz/

Comment: Please note that that typo also invalidates the subsequent declarations in that block.

Comment: Many thanks for the correction. My careless mistakes !